# ¿Cómo crear un ArrayList dentro de un ArrayList?

Tags: java

tengo la duda sobre como añadir objetos dentro de un Arraylist y luego hacer un ArrayList con cada ArrayList como ejemplo teórico, podemos decir que una escuela tiene cursos y cada curso tiene estudiantes
por lo que necesitamos un ArrayList con los estudiantes de cada curso donde tienen atributos como la edad y nombre, pero luego tenemos un ArrayList de cursos

Esta seria la clase Curso:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.sound.midi.Soundbank;

public class Curso {

    private final ArrayList <Estudiante> estudiante;
       
    public void AddEstudiante(){
        Estudiante est = new Estudiante();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sce = new Scanner(System.in);
                
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre: ");
        est.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Ingrese la edad: ");
        est.setEdad(sce.nextInt());      
        estudiante.add(est);         
 
    }
```

Y la clase Control, es decir la clase que debe tener el ArrayList de cursos es esta

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PracticaArrayList {
    
    private final ArrayList <Curso> cursos;
    
    
    public PracticaArrayList(){
    cursos = new ArrayList <Curso>();
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Curso c = new Curso();
        
        Scanner es = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Nombre de curso: ");
        //String nombreC;
        //String numCurso = es.nextLine();
        //addCurso(numCurso);
        System.out.println("Cuantos Estudiantes desea ingresar: ");
        int n = es.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i< n; i++) {
            c.AddEstudiante();
            
        }
        System.out.println("Que estudiante desea buscar: ");
        String nombre = p.nextLine();
        c.BuscarEstud();
       
        System.out.println(c.promEdades());
    
    }   
}
```

Pero no encuentro una forma de añadir este ultimo objeto Curso en el arrayList
espero me puedan ayudar en tal caso, hay algun libro que tenga este tipo de ejercicios
en su mayor parte tienen ejercicios con simples usos de ArrayList
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.cursos.add(c);
```

**PERO** `main` es un método estático (asociado a una clase), y `this.cursos` es un método de instancia (asociado a una instancia de la clase).

Así que puedes definir un método de instancia para añadir el curso

```
public void anyadirCurso(Curso curso) {
   this.cursos.add(curso);
}
```

y desde el `main` **creas una instancia de `PracticaArrayList`** y usas sus métodos:

```
PracticaArrayList practica = new PracticaArrayList();
practica.anyadirCurso(c);
```

Conviene que repases la diferencia entre métodos (y atributos) estáticos y de instancia, y que recuerdes que `main` siempre es estático.

Lo de "añadir un ArrayList dentro de un ArrayList" es un poco confuso. No hay ningún problema en definir un ArrayList de ArrayList (`ArrayList<ArrayList<Curso>> cursos = new ArrayList<>();`). Lo mejor será que lo expliques mejor en otra pregunta (una duda por pregunta).

Comment: Muchas Gracias lo estaré analizando